# Select different wallpaper for each virtual desktop in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, desktop-background

I enjoy virtual desktops and would like them to have different wallpapers in Xubuntu 18.04.

Is this possible, if not by some hidden switch, maybe with some scripting/tweaking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Right-click on the first workspace desktop and select **Desktop Settings**. You will see the image above. Untick **Apply to all workspaces** and set the wallpaper you like. Repeat the process by right-clicking on each workspace desktop.

Comment: You're welcome.